# Ciclo while no termina el bucle a pesar de colocar una condición distinta como parámetro para que lo haga

Tags: javascript, funciones, bucles, while

En este código po más que realicé combinaciones de todo tipo, no encontré como salir del bucle sin que llegue a infinito. El caso es que supuestamente cuando el usuario introduzca "fin" en la condición del while, el mismo finalice, pero nada. Intenté con operacion != "fin" pero nada pues operación está fuera del scope. Pensé que declarando la variable resultado  fuera del ciclo y al colocarle un valor distinto o igual como condición dentro del while, finalizaría el ciclo, pero tampoco.

```
function calcular(operacion, a, b) {
    let resultado = 0;
    if (operacion == "suma") {
        resultado = a + b;
    } else if (operacion == "resta") {
        resultado = a - b;
    } else if (operacion == "multiplicacion") {
        resultado = a * b;
    } else if (operacion == "division") {
        resultado = a / b;
    }
    return resultado
}

while (calcular != "fin") {
    let resultadoFinal = calcular(prompt("Que operacion quiere realizar?"), parseInt(prompt("Ingrese el 1er valor")), parseInt(prompt("Ingrese el 2do valor")));
    alert("La respuesta es " + resultadoFinal);
}
```

Comment: _calcular_ es una función, no una variable...

Comment: pues si, tienes razón @paladeiana pero intenté de otras maneras con elementos de la propia función pero no se puede pues quedarían fuera del scope o incluso de los parámetros que se le pasa a la misma y quizás me mareé. Lo más probable es que deba introducirle elementos dentro del while, como condicionales, pero la idea hubiera sido hacer el código lo más simple y menos extenso posible.

Comment: ¡No olvides depurar tu código! Y hazlo _por partes_. Procura acortar tu código una vez que ya tengas algo resuelto, ¡no lo optimices antes de tiempo! De nuevo, revisa tus variables, y la forma en la que estás llamando a la función.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí lo tienes, tienes que declarar una variable global que va cambiando con lo que recibe por teclado.

```
let operacion;

function calcular(operacion, a, b) {

    let resultado = 0;
    if (operacion == "suma") {
        resultado = a + b;
    } else if (operacion == "resta") {
        resultado = a - b;
    } else if (operacion == "multiplicacion") {
         resultado = a * b;
    } else if (operacion == "division") {
        resultado = a / b;
    }
    return resultado
}

while (operacion != "fin") {
    operacion = prompt("Que operacion quiere realizar?")
    if (operacion != "fin") {
        let resultadoFinal = calcular(operacion, parseInt(prompt("Ingrese el 1er valor")), parseInt(prompt("Ingrese el 2do valor")));
        alert("La respuesta es " + resultadoFinal);
    }
}
```

Comment: De acuerdo @chikebox, lo único que le cambiaría es que en vez de declarar la variable global con var lo haría con let, justo al principio del código, tal cual lo has hecho.

Comment: Tienes razón, editado